# How to avoid search on a particular element with search:search API?

Tags: marklogic

I want to avoid certain elements to be searched in `search:search` (Search API). How can I do this? Whenever we use `search:search` it searches over the whole document and if we want to search on an element we can add searchable expression. But if we don't to search over some elements and want to exclude those elements from the search then how we can do that with `search:search` API ?

Answer (score 2):

You can arrange it so the element does not appear in the indexes. Use a [word-query exclude](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/wordquery#chapter).